# Is there a way to use DropBox for authentication without re-authorization?

Tags: oauth, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm developing a DropBox app - one that has no use if the user is not authenticated by DropBox. Therefore it would be useless to have separate account management in my app, (using the DropBox accounting should suffice).

The oauth sequence suggested by DropBox does both authentication (having the user sign in with her DropBox credentials), and authorization (having her approve my app to access her DB account). This is good for the first time the user signs-in to my app. But once my app is approved and "installed" on the user's account, I don't want her to be prompted whether to allow my app access, every time she logs in. Is there a way to skip the authorization page?

Comment: Unfortunately, the only way it seems to be possible is to maintain a database of authorization tokens on the server. Also see https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=80430 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some time passed, but now there is a way to allow permanent access to dropbox API.
You need to generate access token from the application settings and use it.
Here is what dropbox says:

> By generating an access token, you will be able to make API calls for your own account without going through the authorization flow. To obtain access tokens for other users, use the standard OAuth flow.